# Android application running from android studio but app not installed

Tags: android

I have an android app that is working perfectly when deployed via android studio but when I copy the generated apk from the output folder (app\build\outputs\apk) and install it on the same phone the app crashes up on loading.

Even that upon installation  the OS says that the app does not require any special permissions even though I have these in the manifest file:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Comment: "the app crashes up on loading" -- use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: before taking apk from app\build\outputs\apk, Goto Build>Build APK then 
then try to install in device

Comment: Have you included runtime permissions for some of those? I know you need runtime permissions for `READ_CONTACTS` at least

Comment: @SunilP Thank you, this was the solution, please add it to accept it.

Comment: welcome buddy @HasanShouman

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly ask the user to provide permission to access location and contacts. This is an update that was added to lollipop/Marshmallow.

You might have to do something like this.

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           // The user has granted permission to access location
        } else {
            // The user has not granted permission(notify the user that certain features will not work for the app if the permission is not granted)
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you explain more please and give examples if you can

Comment: Thank you for your effort, however in my case I need to build the app from Build>Build APK...

Comment: @HasanShouman my pleasure. However you can upvote my answer if it helped you :-)